# Monaco-editor does not correctly evaluate negative-lookahead regex

Tags: regex, monaco-editor

I used this `((?=(?!\bTODO\b)*?;).*)((?=.*?\bTODO\b).*)[^\n]` regex to look for TODO inside commented text, its valid javascript regex, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/BO7Pbb/1)

But when I use

```
editor.getModel().findMatches("((?=(?!\\bTODO\\b)*?;).*)((?=.*?\\bTODO\\b).*)[^\\s]", true, true, true, null, true);
```

it returns empty `FindMatch[]`. Removing negative-lookahead `((?=.*?;).*)((?=.*?\bTODO\b).*)[^\n]` it behave correctly, but it match invalid lines, obviously.

It is bug of monaco-editor, or just I do something wrong?

Comment: What a strange regex. I think it is equal to `^(;.*)\b(TODO\b.*)`, a much simpler one. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bo2mx9/1). Does it work for you?

Comment: Its almost working except ';' can be somewhere in middle of line, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zD4fB1/2)

Comment: So, `^([^;]*;.*)\b(TODO\b.*)`? See https://regex101.com/r/zD4fB1/3

Comment: In my case its enough to capture text from ';', so `(;.*)(\bTODO\b.*)` is fine.

Comment: Ah, `^` is redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(;.*)(\bTODO\b.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zD4fB1/4).

**Details**

- `(;.*)` - Group 1: a `;` and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(\bTODO\b.*)` - `TODO` as a whole word and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.